# Resize an ImageIcon for an JLabel

Tags: java, image, swing, resize, imageicon

I created a class called VainillaImagen:

```
public VainillaImage(String url){
    this.icimg=new ImageIcon(url);
    this.imagen=new JLabel(this.icimg);
    this.imagen.setVisible(true);
}
```

and then I created a methos called setDimensions that use another method called resizeVainillaImg. But the resizeVainillaImg method dont work any ideas why?

```
public void setDimensions(boolean wRel,int width,boolean hRel,int height){
    Dimension dimPantalla = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int nwidth,nheight;
    if(wRel){
        nwidth=(int)(width*(dimPantalla.width));
    }else{
        nwidth=width;
    }
    if(hRel){
        nheight=(int)(height*(dimPantalla.height));
    }else{
        nheight=height;
    }
    resizeVainillaImg(nwidth,nheight);
}


public void resizeVainillaImg(int newWidth,int newHeight){
    Image img = this.icimg.getImage();
    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(newWidth,newHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g = bi.createGraphics();
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight,null);
    g.dispose();
    this.icimg = new ImageIcon(bi);
    this.imagen.setIcon(this.icimg);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I didn't understand the setDimensions(), but I think you are trying to fit your image into screen width and height.

By multiplying int values of width and height in setDimensions(), you will simply be able to multiply small int numbers. For bigger numbers you will run out of memory because of huge image size (width*screenwidth , height*screenheight).

Lets assume you want to resize your image to percent of your screen, or use the default height and with of the image. Using the code below, pass negative number (-1 for example) to ignore the screen size, and 0> number to resize it to percent of screen.

I hope this help. However, it you have some other think in your mind, just remember to use float because of int * int multiplications :)

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

/**
 *
 * @author Pasban
 */
public class VainillaImage {

    private ImageIcon icimg;
    private JLabel imagen;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JDialog d = new JDialog();
        VainillaImage v = new VainillaImage("92-1024x576.jpg");
        d.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        d.getContentPane().add(v.imagen);
        v.setDimensions(-1, 1);
        d.pack();
        d.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        d.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void setDimensions(double width, double height) {
        Dimension dimPantalla = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int nwidth, nheight;
        nwidth = (int) (width * (dimPantalla.width));
        nheight = (int) (height * (dimPantalla.height));
        resizeVainillaImg(nwidth, nheight);
    }

    public void resizeVainillaImg(int newWidth, int newHeight) {
        Image img = this.icimg.getImage();
        newWidth = Math.max(newWidth, img.getHeight(null));
        newWidth = Math.max(newHeight, img.getHeight(null));
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(newWidth, newHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g = bi.createGraphics();
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight, null);
        g.dispose();
        this.icimg = new ImageIcon(bi);
        this.imagen.setIcon(this.icimg);
    }

    public VainillaImage(String url) {
        this.icimg = new ImageIcon(url);
        this.imagen = new JLabel(this.icimg);
        this.imagen.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to dynamically resize an Icon based on the space available to the label then check out Darryl's [Stretch Icon](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/stretch-icon/).